# Find out if city name occurs in string

Tags: python-2.7, trie, city

I have a list of cities, such as 'San Luis Obispo', I then have a sentence such as

> Michael lives in San Luis Obispo

Note the city can occur **anywhere** in the sentence. I parse the sentence word by word. 
How would I check if 'San Luis Obispo' is in my list of cities? 
I'm using a [marisa-trie](https://github.com/kmike/marisa-trie) to store the list of cities, but can't figure out how to get a 'false, but keep going' when I check the word "San". Should I switch to a different data structure or write a custom trie?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do simple string checks? Ie `'san luis obispo' in sentence.lower()` ?

Comment: Yes, the list of cities that could occur in the sentences is very large . 'san luis obispo' is only one city that could occur in the sentences.

Comment: You're going to have to show some actual code, I think - how the trie is structured, that sort of thing.

Comment: <pre><code>
    # L is a list of the cities  
    trie = marisa_trie.Trie(L)  
  
    # str is the sentence  
    words = word_tokenize(str)  
    for w in words:  
        word = unicode(w.lower)  
        if word in trie:  
            # a city name has been found in the sentence  
        else:  
            # Is this word the first word in a multi-word city name  
            if trie.has_keys_with_prefix(word):  
                # Concatenate with a space and next word  
            else:  
                # Move on to next word

Comment: @a-p 
I believe this is the answer:
http://pastebin.com/yE2Nrd5C

Comment: The above solution will not work as the method has_keys_with_prefix(word) will match any prefix, not just a word prefix. For example the method will return true for the word 'ant' as it is the prefix in the city 'antioch'. marisa-trie are not the way to go. Will write my own python implementation of a trie.